# Latency When I’m Using get_head_info

Tags: dfuse

When using the get_head_info, the data is always pushed intermittently. For example, if there’s no data pushed in the first 1-5 seconds, then it would all come in on the 6th second. Is this caused by network congestion?

Answer (score 1):

- Please confirm the IP address you are resolving through DNS
  `nslookup mainnet.eos.dfuse.io`  (it should be `35.186.231.197`)
- Please provide `mtr` network latency performance results
  `mtr -T -P 443 35.186.231.197`